# Getting app version from playstore in cordova

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, security, https

I'm trying to get the app versión of the app uploaded in playstore, i'm truying to use https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id with this code

```
var url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=' + appID;
           $.ajax({
                url: your_url,
                type: 'GET',
                crossDomain:true,
                success: function(res) {
                    let storeVersion =null;
                    var doc=null;
                    var tag=null;
                    var parser = new DOMParser(),
                    doc = parser.parseFromString(res, 'text/html');
                    if (doc) 
                    {
                        tag = doc.querySelectorAll(".hAyfc .htlgb");
                        if (tag && tag[6]) {
                            storeVersion = tag[6].innerText.trim();
                        }
                    }
            });
```

in an emulator works correctly but in a physical device it return error 403, i tried putting a lot of options in the content security policy

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; img-src * data: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' ; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *; connect-src * data: https: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' https://play.google.com">
```

but none work, am i missing something? is there another way of getting the playstore version?

Answer (score 0):

Please check `config.xml` and make sure that these lines already added.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

What version of Cordova and Cordova Android did you use?

And did you already install `cordova-plugin-whitelist`?

Comment: Hi, i have those lines in config.xml, I'm using cordova 8.1.2 and cordova android 8.0.0 and have cordova whitelist 1.3.4